# Understanding & Converting ThinkScripts CompoundValue Function

Tags: technical-indicator, thinkscript

I'm currently converting a ThinkScript indicator to C#, however, I've run into this [`CompoundValue`](https://tlc.thinkorswim.com/center/reference/thinkScript/Functions/Others/CompoundValue.html) function and I'm unsure how to covert it.

The documents reads :

> Calculates a compound value according to following rule: if a bar
>   number is greater than length then the visible data value is returned,
>   otherwise the historical data value is returned. This function is used
>   to initialize studies with recursion.

Example Use:

```
declare lower;
def x = CompoundValue(2, x[1] + x[2], 1);
plot FibonacciNumbers = x;
```

**My interpretation:**

Based on description and example. It appears we are passing a calculation in `x[1] + x[2]` and it performing this calculation on the current bar and the previous bar (based on first param of `2`). I'm unsure what the parameter `1` is for.

**My Question:**

Please explain what this function is actually doing. If possible, please illustrate how this method works using pseudo-code.

Comment: I think your code is similar to the one in this page and there is a clear description for the third parameter(https://tlc.thinkorswim.com/center/reference/thinkScript/Functions/Others/CompoundValue.html).

Comment: Perhaps the 1 is clearly defined, that doesn’t mean the question is invalid. If the internals of CompoundValue were plainly obvious I wouldn’t have dumped 100 points into a bounty.

Comment: I am not saying your question is pointless, I am just answering part of the question where you mentioned you was unsure what the parameter 1 is for.

Comment: Sorry, it was the first part “I think your code is similar to the one on this page” that made me assume you were implying that. Apologies.

Comment: No worry. It is all good.

Comment: After reading through the description and some information. I don't think that function does anything. Its description also wrong on the length part. Their description page mentioned if bar > length then visible data will be returned. But that is not the case with their example. That is because of the 2 in their example. That shouldn't be a returned value if bar > length. That is bar > or = length.

Comment: Basically that function only do one thing. Let say we have (1st param, 2nd param, and 3rd param). Base on their description, if 2nd param > 1st param then return 2nd param. Else return 3rd param. That is for that function, the way how you can get it to work is base on other support code. Also, be aware that their description to that function could be wrong base on the example that they gave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please let me provide two equivalent working versions of the code in thinkscript itself. We use this approach to prove equivalence by subtracting the equivalent outputs from each other - the result should be 0.

```
# The original Fibonacci code with a parameter "length" added.
# That parameter is the first parameter of the CompoundValue function.
declare lower;
def length = 2;
def x = CompoundValue(length, x[1] + x[2], 1);
# plot FibonacciNumbers = x;

# Equivalent code using the `if` statement:
def y;
if(BarNumber() > length){
    # Visible data. This is within the guarded branch of the if statement.
    # Historical data y[1] (1 bar back) and y[2] (2 bars back) is available
    y = y[1] + y[2];
}else{
    # Not enough historical data so we use the special case satisfying the
    # original rule.
    y = 1;
}
plot FibonacciNumbersDiff = y - x;
```

Thinkscript "recursion" is a somewhat inflated term. The function name `CompoundValue` is not very helpful so it may create confusion.

The version using the `if` statement is more useful in general because when walking through the time series of bars, we often need a program structure with multiple nested `if` statements - this cannot be done with the `CompoundValue` function. Please see my other articles which make use of this in the context of scanning.

In Java, using the same structure, it looks like this:

```
int size = 100;
int length = 2;
int[] values = new int[size];
for(int index = 1; index < size; index++){
    if(index > length){
        values[index] = values[index - 1] + values[index - 2];
    }else{
        values[index] = 1;
    }
}
```

The fundamental difference is the `for` loop which is not present in the thinkscript code. thinkscript provides the loop in a kind of inversion of control where it executes user code multiple times, once for each bar.

Answer (score 4):

For the TLDR; crowd, some simple code that hopefully explains what the `CompoundValue()` function is trying to do, and which might help in converting it's functionality:

```
# from: Chapter 12. Past/Future Offset and Prefetch
# https://tlc.thinkorswim.com/center/reference/thinkScript/tutorials/Advanced/Chapter-12---Past-Offset-and-Prefetch

# According to this tutorial, thinkScript uses the highest offset, overriding
#   all lower offsets in the script - WOW


declare lower;

# recursive addition using x[1] is overridden by 11 in the plot for
#   Average(close, 11) below; SO `x = x[1] + 1` becomes `x = x[11] + 1`
def x = x[1] + 1;

# using CompoundValue, though, we can force the use of the *desired* value
# arguments are:
# - length: the number of bars for this variable's offset (`1` here)
# - "visible data": value to use IF VALUES EXIST for a bar (a calculation here)
# - "historical data": value to use IF NO VALUE EXISTS for a bar (`1` here)
def y = CompoundValue(1, y[1] + 1, 1);

# *plotting* this Average statement will change ALL offsets to 11!
plot Average11 = Average(close, 11); 

# `def`ing the offset DOES NOT change other offsets, so no issue here
#    (if the `def` setup DID change the offsets, then `x[1]` would 
#    become `x[14]`, as 14 is higher than 11. However, `x[1]` doesn't change.
def  Average14 = Average(close, 14);

plot myline = x;
plot myline2 = y;

# add some labels to tell us what thinkScript calculated
def numBars = HighestAll(BarNumber());
AddLabel(yes, "# Bars on Chart: " + numBars, Color.YELLOW);
AddLabel(yes, "x @ bar 1: " + GetValue(x, numBars), Color.ORANGE);
AddLabel(yes, "x @ bar " + numBars + ": " + x, Color.ORANGE);

AddLabel(yes, "y @ bar 1: " + GetValue(y, numBars), Color.LIGHT_ORANGE);
AddLabel(yes, "y @ bar " + numBars + ": " + y, Color.ORANGE);
```

---

Now, some, er, *lots of* details...

First, **a quick note on "offset" values**:

thinkScript, like other trading-related languages, uses an internal looping system. This is like a `for` loop, iterating through all the "periods" or "bars" on a chart (eg, 1 bar = 1 day on a daily chart; 1 bar = 1 minute on a 1 minute intraday chart, etc). Every line of code in thinkScript is run for *each and every bar* in the chart or length of time specified in the script.

As noted by the OP, `x[1]` represents an offset of one bar *before* the current bar the loop is processing. `x[2]` represents two bars before the current bar, and so on. Additionally, it's possible to offset into the future by using negative numbers: `x[-1]` means one bar *ahead* of the current bar, for example.

These offsets work similarly to the `for` loop in C#, except they're backwards: `x[0]` in C# would represent the current `x` value, as it would in thinkScript; however, moving forward in the loop, `x[1]` would be the *next* value, and `x[-1]` wouldn't exist because, well, there is no past value before 0. (In general, of course! One can definitely loop with negative numbers in C#. The point is that positive offset indices in thinkScript represent *past* bars, while negative offset indices in thinkScript represent *future* bars - not the case in C#.)

Also important here is the concept of "length": in thinkScript, `length` parameters represent the distance you want to go - like the offset, but a range instead of one specific bar. In my example code above, I used the statement `plot Average11 = Average(close, 11);` In this case, the `11` parameter represents plotting the close for a period of 11 bars, ie, offsets `x[0]` through `x[10]`.

Now, to explain **the CompoundValue() function's purpose**:

The [Chapter 12. Past/Future Offset and Prefetch](https://tlc.thinkorswim.com/center/reference/thinkScript/tutorials/Advanced/Chapter-12---Past-Offset-and-Prefetch) thinkScript tutorial explains that thinkScript actually *overrides* smaller offset or length values with the highest value in a script. What that means is that if you have two items defined as follows:

```
def x = x[1] + 1;
plot Average11 = Average(close, 11);
```

thinkScript will actually override the `x[1]` offset with the higher length used in the Average statement - therefore causing `x[1]` to become `x[11]`!

Yike! That means that the specified offsets, except the highest offset, mean nothing to thinkScript! So, wait a minute - does one *have* to use all the same offsets for everything, then? No! This is where CompoundValue() comes in...

That same chapter explains that CompoundValue() allows one to specify an offset for a variable *that won't be changed, even if a higher offset exists*.

**The [CompoundValue()](https://tlc.thinkorswim.com/center/reference/thinkScript/Functions/Others/CompoundValue) function, with parameter labels, looks like this**:

```
CompoundValue(length, "visible data", "historical data")
```

As the OP noted, this isn't really particularly clear. Here's what the parameters represent:

- **length**: the offset number of bars for this variable.

  In our example, `def x = x[1] + 1`, there is a 1 bar offset, so our statement starts as `CompoundValue(length=1, ...)`. If instead, it was a larger offset, say 14 bars, we'd put `CompoundValue(length=14, ...)`
- **"visible data"**: the value or calculation thinkScript should perform *if DATA IS AVAILABLE for the current bar*.

  Again, in our example, we're using a calculation of `x[1] + 1`, so `CompoundValue(length=1, "visible data"=(x[1] + 1), ...)`. (Parentheses around the equation aren't necessary, but may help with clarity.)
- **"historical data"**: the value to use *if NO DATA IS AVAILABLE for the current bar*.

  In our example, if no data is available, we'll use a value of `1`.

Now, in thinkScript, parameter labels aren't required if the arguments are in order and/or defaults are supplied. So, we could write this CompoundValue statement like this *without* the labels:

`def y = CompoundValue(1, y[1] + 1, 1);`

or like this *with* the labels:

`def y = CompoundValue(length=1, "visible data"=(y[1] + 1), "historical data"=1);`

(Note that parameter names containing spaces have to be surrounded by double quotes. Single-word parameter names don't need the quotes. Also, I've placed parens around the equation just for the sake of clarity; this is not required.)

**In summary**: CompoundValue(...) is needed to ensure a variable uses the actual desired offset/number of bars in a system (thinkScript) that otherwise *overrides* the specified offsets with a higher number if present.

If all the offsets in a script are the same, or if one is using a different programming system, then CompoundValue() can simply be broken down into its appropriate calculations or values, eg `def x = x[1] + 1` or, alternatively, an `if/else` statement that fills in the values desired at whatever bars or conditions are needed.