# Can't understand how it works (ThinkScript code)

Tags: technical-indicator, thinkscript

I'm currently converting a ThinkScript indicator to python, however, I've run into this piece of code and I'm kinda confused on how it works:

```
input rollingPeriodMinutes = 60;


def factor = (SecondsFromTime(Market_Open_Time) / (60 * rollingPeriodMinutes) / 100);
def rolloverTime = if factor == Round(factor) then 1 else 0;


rec H1 = compoundValue(1, if !rolloverTime then if high > H1[1] then high else H1[1] else high, high);
rec H = compoundValue(1, if rolloverTime then H1[1] else H[1], high);
```

I can't really understand what is stored at the end in the variable "H". Can you help me understand?
Any help is really appraciated!! Thanks

Comment: Are you confused *only* about `H`? Or, `H1` also? Is it `compoundValue(...)` you're confused about? Or, is it the `rec` declaration?

Answer (score 0):

`input rollingPeriodMinutes = 60;`

- declares (`def`ines) and sets a variable, `rollingPeriodMinutes`, to a default value of `60`. The `input` declaration indicates that the user will be able to alter this value in the thinkorswim settings for this script.

`def factor = (SecondsFromTime(Market_Open_Time) / (60 * rollingPeriodMinutes) / 100);`

- declares and sets a variable, `factor` to a calculated value. This uses the `rollingPeriodMinutes` value, above, as well as the [`SecondsFromTime` function](https://tlc.thinkorswim.com/center/reference/thinkScript/Functions/Date---Time/SecondsFromTime.html) and a `Market_Open_Time` variable that must have been set elsewhere in the script.

`def rolloverTime = if factor == Round(factor) then 1 else 0;`

- declares and sets a variable, `rolloverTime` to a boolean based on the `if` statement. This uses the `factor` variable above (`1` is true and `0` is false in thinkscript).

```
rec H1 = compoundValue(1, if !rolloverTime then if high > H1[1] then high else H1[1] else high, high);
rec H = compoundValue(1, if rolloverTime then H1[1] else H[1], high);
```

- [`rec` is actually the same as `def`](https://tlc.thinkorswim.com/center/reference/thinkScript/Reserved-Words/rec.html) and has been obsoleted. Previously, it specifically declared a recursive variable; now one would just use `def` regardless. See the notes below for more information.

  [`CompoundValue`](https://tlc.thinkorswim.com/center/reference/thinkScript/Functions/Others/CompoundValue) is an easy statement in thinkscript, but complicated to understand from the [Learning Center reference](https://tlc.thinkorswim.com/center/reference/thinkScript/Functions/Others/CompoundValue).

  In short, the declarations for `H` and `H1` are saying 'going back 1 bar: if no data is present, then use the `if` statement to determine a value; else if data *is* present, then use the `high` value.

  Broken out, the algorithm for `H1` (where `high` is a reserved word for the high price for a given bar) could look like:

```
let numBarsBack = 1
if (data is present for the bar at numBarsBack) then
  if (!rolloverTime == true) then
    if high > (H1 value one bar previous) then H1 = high
    else H1 = (H1 value one bar previous)
    else H1 = high    // thinkscript sometimes requires a "default" in `if` statements, even if there's no 3rd possible value
  else (if rolloverTime == true) then H1 = high
else (if data is not present for the bar at numBarsBack) then H1 = high
```

---

*** See my complete description of how `CompoundValue` works in thinkscript at the SO question ["Understanding & Converting ThinkScripts CompoundValue Function"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66807977/1107226).***

---

Notes:

- `SecondsFromTime`, according to the [current thinkscript Learning Center reference](https://tlc.thinkorswim.com/center/reference/thinkScript/Functions/Date---Time/SecondsFromTime.html) looks like:

> SecondsFromTime ( int fromTime);
>
> Description
>
> Returns the number of seconds from the specified time (24-hour clock notation) in the EST timezone. Note that this function always returns zero when chart's aggregation period is greater than or equal to 1 day.
>
> Input parameters
>
> Parameter  Default value   Description
> fromTime   -   Defines time from which seconds are counted, in the HHMM format, 24-hour clock notation.

- The [Learning Center reference for `rec`](https://tlc.thinkorswim.com/center/reference/thinkScript/Reserved-Words/rec.html) says this:

> rec
>
> Notice: this is an article about an obsolete thinkScript® notation. Although rec variables are still supported by thinkScript®, they can be completely replaced by def.
>
> Syntax
>
> rec
>
> Description
>
> Enables you to reference a historical value of a variable that you are calculating in the study or strategy itself. Rec is short for "recursion".
>
> Example
>
> ```
> rec C = C[1] + volume;  
> plot CumulativeVolume = C;
> ```
>
> This example plots the cumulative volume starting from the beginning of the time period.

and, finally:

- Remember that thinkscript code is executed for every bar in a selected period. Ie, if you're looking at 10 days with a daily period, there will be a bar for each of the 10 days; and the script will run a loop, repeating the code for each of those 10 bars. As a result, the variables will have appropriate values for each bar.

  *Although the OP is wanting to convert a script to Python, if someone comes here interested in how thinkscript works, there are tricks to keep a value constant for an entire script (though this section of code does not include examples for that). For information on how to do this in thinkscript, see [my answer to SO question "thinkscript - How to create a variable that retains its value"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66894945/1107226).*